# CSS3 Not Displaying Background Image + Gradient on HTML element

Tags: html, css

In general, I know that it is possible to use CSS3 to specify multiple backgrounds, and I have successfully overlaid a gradient on top of an image before.  However, this seems to fail when applied to the base `html` element.  In both Chrome and Firefox, the gradient is not rendered in the CSS below:

```
html {
    background:#14283C;
    background-image:url('/images/bluenoise.png?1338342472'),-webkit-gradient(radial, center 8em, 0, center 8em, 100, color-stop(0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.2)), color-stop(100%, rgba(255,255,255,0)));
    background-image:url('/images/bluenoise.png?1338342472'),-webkit-radial-gradient(center 8em, ellipse closest-corner, rgba(255,255,255,0.2),rgba(255,255,255,0));
    background-image:url('/images/bluenoise.png?1338342472'),-moz-radial-gradient(center 8em, ellipse closest-corner, rgba(255,255,255,0.2),rgba(255,255,255,0));
    background-image:url('/images/bluenoise.png?1338342472'),-o-radial-gradient(center 8em, ellipse closest-corner, rgba(255,255,255,0.2),rgba(255,255,255,0));
    background-image:url('/images/bluenoise.png?1338342472'),-ms-radial-gradient(center 8em, ellipse closest-corner, rgba(255,255,255,0.2),rgba(255,255,255,0));
    background-image:url('/images/bluenoise.png?1338342472'),radial-gradient(center 8em, ellipse closest-corner, rgba(255,255,255,0.2),rgba(255,255,255,0));
}
```

If I apply the same styles to `body`, the gradient is rendered correctly.  Any thoughts on why there would be this difference?

Comment: `html` isn't added to the render tree is my guess.

Comment: @alex you can apply styles like color or bg-picture though.

Comment: @Christoph `color` would make sense because of inheritance, `background-image` not so much.

Comment: btw @Jeff, it works for me. Must be something with your code. http://jsfiddle.net/D9B4q/ (only webkit for simplicity)

Comment: for me too using chrome 19.0.1084.52

Comment: Works for me, I think -- but not sure what it's supposed to look like exactly.

Comment: @alex Why would color make sense? `html` has no parent to inherit from. And the other elements could easily inherit from body. But since `html` is the root element of your document I'm pretty sure it is stylable as like every other element.

Comment: @Christoph I was talking about descendants of the `html` element inheriting it.

Comment: Why not just use `body`? Using `html` is not the correct form.

Comment: @Ian My current solution is precisely that; I put the gradient on `body`, however, my design gives `body` a max width, so for wide windows, the gradient gets cut off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried some of the tricks mentioned in the comments, but what ended up working is the following:

```
html{
    background:#14283C;
    background-image:-webkit-gradient(radial, center 8em, 0, center 8em, 100, color-stop(0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.2)), color-stop(100%, rgba(255,255,255,0))),url('/images/bluenoise.png?1338386219');
    background-image:-webkit-radial-gradient(center 8em, ellipse closest-corner, rgba(255,255,255,0.2),rgba(255,255,255,0)),url('/images/bluenoise.png?1338386219');
    background-image:-moz-radial-gradient(center 8em, ellipse closest-corner, rgba(255,255,255,0.2),rgba(255,255,255,0)),url('/images/bluenoise.png?1338386219');
    background-image:-o-radial-gradient(center 8em, ellipse closest-corner, rgba(255,255,255,0.2),rgba(255,255,255,0)),url('/images/bluenoise.png?1338386219');
    background-image:-ms-radial-gradient(center 8em, ellipse closest-corner, rgba(255,255,255,0.2),rgba(255,255,255,0)),url('/images/bluenoise.png?1338386219');
    background-image:radial-gradient(center 8em, ellipse closest-corner, rgba(255,255,255,0.2),rgba(255,255,255,0)),url('/images/bluenoise.png?1338386219');
}
```

The only change is that I list the gradients **before** the images.  It looks like the various `background-image` arguments are overlaid in reverse order.  This explanation, though, would seem to be contradicted by ScottS's fiddle, which also shows the desired behavior despite giving the opposite ordering.

Comment: Just as a note, your new order is [correct according to the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#layering), which states: "The first image in the list is the layer closest to the user, the next one is painted behind the first, and so on. The background color, if present, is painted below all of the other layers." The fact that it worked "incorrectly" in my fiddle is odd.

Answer (score 1):

The [fiddle link Christoph posted](http://jsfiddle.net/D9B4q/) worked for me as well in Chrome. To get the overlay functioning in Firefox, I had to add either a `height` or `min-height: 100%` to the `html` element. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D9B4q/12/).

However, simply having *content* gave height as well, and also allowed the background to work for Firefox as [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D9B4q/13/) shows.

Apparently, the gradient needs some kind of actual height to the element to render in Firefox.

Comment: Your fiddle indeed shows the behavior I'm expecting.  I tried adding a `min-height` as you suggested, but see no difference.

Comment: @JeffKlukas--So you saw the fiddle render okay, but when you added `min-height` to your original code, it had no affect? That is strange. Other than changing the alpha value to `0.8` from `0.2` in my example (to make it more visible) and having a different `background-image` url, the code was like yours. Is it possible that your issue is partly due to either your particular image, or the `0.2` value is so faded that you are not seeing the effect?

Comment: Yes, I tried the `min-height` trick to no effect.  I just put together [my own fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jklukas/3rvzf/1/) which accesses the image actually used on my site.  It puts the gradient first in the list and displays correctly, just as I saw on the production site.

Comment: @JeffKlukas--you say "displays correctly, just as I saw on the production site." Where are you seeing it not displaying correctly using `min-height`?

Comment: On my site, when the image comes before the gradient in `background-image`, no gradient is displayed, whether `min-height` is specified or not.  When the gradient is placed before the image, I see the gradient correctly overlaid on the image.  I produced [a new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jklukas/aAex6/) with `min-height` specified and gradients placed first which demonstrates the problem.